# What ratio of fuel is needed for launching a mass up to low earth orbit compared to the Lagrange point?

Tags: rockets, lunar-landing

I've heard an argument that moon landing was at best improbable as it would have required too much more fuel than simply achieving LEO. It seems to me that it would be relatively little more. I'm just looking for a percentage of fuel burned after clearing the atmosphere by a craft headed for the Lagrange point.

To further simplify the problem, we can assume that the launch is straight up, the Moon is stationary with respect to the launch point and the final velocity upon reaching the Lagrange point is 0.

For practical purposes, I think fuel weight would have to be included in the ratio, but that stage separation can be neglected as it tremendously complicates things and the entire launch mass, minus all fuel, reaches the Lagrange point.

Bonus: To what degree does it matter whether the moon is new or full?

Comment: The "lunar module"??

Comment: LOL. No? How about "the mass"?

Comment: I believe the closing of this question to be wrongheaded and neglectful of the degree of brilliance in its conception and simplicity.

Comment: One notable problem with the question as currently phrased is that there is no point at all in trying to calculate distance a rocket can go without including fairly realistic values for staging, orbital maneuvers, and so forth, because adding even an extra 500 m/s delta-V can end up increasing the launch mass by quite a large fraction, and likewise, neglecting staging gives the ludicrous result of trying to calculate the size of not just an SSTO (which still hasn't been built), but a single-stage-to-lunar-surface-and-return, which just isn't possible with chemical rockets.

Comment: I think comparing Saturn V with a rocket capable of bringing the CSM+LM to Earth orbit would be a good start.

Comment: "Relative distance" is still a misconception for understanding the cost of reaching the moon, but I can take a stab at the question in this edited form.

Comment: 1)  Distance is pretty much irrelevant, it's the velocity change that matters.  2)  Fuel use is **exponential** on velocity change.  Thus it matters what fuel you're using.  That being said, you're looking at 9.3km/sec minimum to orbit and 6.4 from there to the lunar surface (and some for safety).

Comment: You should rewrite your question. What do you want to know? the optimal ratio fuel/mass for LEO? The optimal ratio fuel/mass for launching from the moon and achiving stable circular orbit around the moon at 100 km above ground level? The same ratio for other orbits? Any other indicator?

Comment: Answering this question as it stands would require a number of assumptions, and those assumptions are rather important to understanding the significance of the answer. Simply stating a ratio based on a particular mission with a particular architecture would overlook all the many things that are different about how you get to LEO vs how you land on the Mon. I agree with Hobbes, perhaps the best thing to do is say how much of the fuel of the actual Apollo missions was used after LEO. And mention all the things about that - the staging, the different fuels, the margins...

Comment: @LorenPechtel Cool velocity comparison, but irrelevant. I've edited the question so as to obviate this factor. We could be talking a constant velocity of 1m/s all the way - doesn't matter.

Comment: @TomRussell Calling my numbers irrelevant shows that you don't understand the reality of rockets.  Rockets move at close to the most fuel-efficient trajectories possible--and my numbers are what those trajectories use.  It's not like a car where you have to keep pressure on the gas to keep going.  A rocket burns for minutes to put it on the right trajectory, then it turns off it's engines and coasts.  For the moon that's a few days (for unmanned stuff it could be a month--there's a slow way that uses less fuel), for some of NASA's deep space stuff it can be a decade.

Comment: As for a new moon vs a full moon, that makes no difference at all.  However, where it is in it's orbit **does** make a tiny difference for the return trip.  Earth to moon you simply have to match it's orbit, but moon to Earth you merely need to touch the atmosphere, a match is not required.  The return burn is a tiny bit smaller when the moon is at the far point of it's orbit vs the near point.  (You hit the atmosphere a tiny bit  faster but not enough to make a difference to your heat shield.)

Comment: @LorenPechtel Granted about the realities of rockets. What I'm asking is simply the relative amounts of fuel to propel a rocket to two different altitudes. But I may have an incorrect assumption of linearity in the equation.

Comment: @TomRussell Yes, you are making an incorrect assumption.  The rocket equation is exponential and by the time you're in space it's quite brutal--that's why NASA will jump through all sorts of hoops to save a bit of velocity change.  (Look up the path that the Messenger probe took!)

Comment: @TomRussell And a second misconception--if your objective is deep space it's cheaper to go into orbit first.  It seems strange but the velocity it takes to get to a place such as the moon is pretty much independent of the direction of that velocity.  However, while your rocket burns gravity is pulling it back down--and fuel is spent to counter that that doesn't actually help you get where you are going.  The more horizontal velocity you pile on the less fuel is spent countering gravity.

Comment: @TomRussell Thus your optimum trajectory is to burn vertically just enough to clear any obstacles in your way.  (Note that the atmosphere is an obstacle, you climb above **most** of it before piling on too much velocity.)

Comment: I think I'm going to move this question into the physics forum and attempt to rephrase more as a more general question involving mass, velocity and gravity. BTW, the "new vs full moon" thing was just me wondering how much help we get by launching toward the sun. But I imagine it's relatively none.